# Spring Application Context refresh at runtime

Tags: java, spring, jboss, applicationcontext

we have a problem in our application. We have to refresh the Application Context at runtime because there are some properties in config.properties that are reloaded when the file change. These properties have to be injected into beans. We refresh the application context when file change. But the application is deployed under JBoss and if a request come when the Application Context is refreshing obviously this request generate the error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
```

So we need to know if there are safer methods to reload properties into the Application Context that don't cause lost requests.
Also we need to know if the restart of JBoss is better than reload Application Context. Every help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: did you configure listener in web.xml

Comment: The problem is of concurrency. The getBeanFactory() method should not be allowed while refreshBeanFactory() is running. You have to synchronize implementation of AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext. Can you add the source code of your implementation.

Comment: Listener in web.xml is needed if we have more than one context right? So why in this case is it useful?

Comment: We use the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and the method refresh(). I can't add source code.